# Как сгруппировать массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Всем хорошего настроения.
Помогите несчастному сгруппировать такой массив.

```html
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_1"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Vka124"
      ["login"]=>
      string(6) "Vka124"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "Vka124"
      ["password"]=>
      string(6) "Vka124"
      [3]=>
      string(15) "Vka124@gmail.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(15) "Vka124@gmail.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-25 13:38:45"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-25 13:38:45"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_1"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "balon777"
      ["login"]=>
      string(8) "balon777"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "balon777"
      ["password"]=>
      string(8) "balon777"
      [3]=>
      string(18) "balon777@gmail.com"
      ["email"]=>
      string(18) "balon777@gmail.com"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-25 13:39:24"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-25 13:39:24"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_1"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "pamir2"
      ["login"]=>
      string(6) "pamir2"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "pamir"
      ["password"]=>
      string(5) "pamir"
      [3]=>
      string(15) "pamir2@pamir.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(15) "pamir2@pamir.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 14:14:55"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 14:14:55"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 14:15:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 14:15:00"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [8]=>
      string(38) "../avatar/pamir2-20170830142301848.jpg"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(38) "../avatar/pamir2-20170830142301848.jpg"
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_2"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "mansari"
      ["login"]=>
      string(7) "mansari"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "123456"
      ["password"]=>
      string(6) "123456"
      [3]=>
      string(16) "mansari@gmail.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "mansari@gmail.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_3"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "tester"
      ["login"]=>
      string(6) "tester"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "tester"
      ["password"]=>
      string(6) "tester"
      [3]=>
      string(20) "tester@tester.tester"
      ["email"]=>
      string(20) "tester@tester.tester"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:41:02"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:41:02"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_4"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "12"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "12"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "devtools"
      ["login"]=>
      string(8) "devtools"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "devtools"
      ["password"]=>
      string(8) "devtools"
      [3]=>
      string(20) "devtools@devtools.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(20) "devtools@devtools.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:42:00"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:42:00"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_5"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "13"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "13"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "kalibrius"
      ["login"]=>
      string(9) "kalibrius"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "kalibrius"
      ["password"]=>
      string(9) "kalibrius"
      [3]=>
      string(23) "kalibrius@kalibrius.com"
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "kalibrius@kalibrius.com"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:43:35"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:43:35"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(2) "12"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(2) "12"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_4"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "bagdat"
      ["login"]=>
      string(6) "bagdat"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "bagdat"
      ["password"]=>
      string(6) "bagdat"
      [3]=>
      string(14) "bagdat@mail.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "bagdat@mail.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:52:52"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 18:52:52"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    ["level_1"]=>
    array(28) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "16"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "16"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "raketa099"
      ["login"]=>
      string(9) "raketa099"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "raketa099"
      ["password"]=>
      string(9) "raketa099"
      [3]=>
      string(17) "raketa099@mail.ru"
      ["email"]=>
      string(17) "raketa099@mail.ru"
      [4]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 23:01:57"
      ["regdate"]=>
      string(19) "2017-08-30 23:01:57"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [6]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ["last_visit"]=>
      string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      [7]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["referrer"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["link_vk"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["skype_login"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["youtube_link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email_contakt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["perfect_purse"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Нужно чтобы можно было обратиться к обьекту по `level_` например как то так

```
echo $array["level_1"][0]["login"]
```

В массив `level_1`, `level_2` и так далее у меня попадают пользователи. Вот мне и нужно сгруппировать массив таким образом, чтобы я мог вытащить информацию по человеку который в массиве, например, `level_1`

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если учесть, что в вашем `$array[$idx]` может быть только один элемент `level_X`, то решение может быть, например, следующим:

Исходные данные:

```
$data = [
    0 => [ "level_1" => ['login' => 'test-1-1']],
    1 => [ "level_1" => ['login' => 'test-1-2']],
    2 => [ "level_2" => ['login' => 'test-2-1']],
];
```

Преобразование:

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $v){
     $result[key($v)][] = current($v);
}
print_r($result);
```

В таком случае функции `key()` и `current()` изначально указывают на первый и единственный элемент `level_*` в массиве.
Если по какой-то причине вам не нравится использование цикла, то можете использовать функцию `array_walk` для обхода массива, но сути это не меняет:

```
$result2 = [];
array_walk($data, function($v) use (&$result2){ $result2[key($v)][] = current($v);});
print_r($result2);
```

Comment: То что нужно, Огромное вам спасибо, целий день сегодня мучался с этим массивом.